# Setting breakpoints to Mozilla libraries using Visual Studio does not halt

Tags: c++, firefox, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio, break points set in the Mozilla project's libraries, say **dom_media_webaudio** or **dom_network**, doesn't halt at that location.

I have compiled the most recent source of Mozilla on Windows 64 bits (VS 2015 community, update 3).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites

I also created a Visual Studio project so I could view the code 
https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/file/default/build/docs/visualstudio.rst

Setting additional flags in .mozconfig like *ac_add_options --enable-debug* and a*c_add_options --disable-optimize*
slows Firefox to a halt and doesn't do much for debugging those libraries.

Does anyone know how to do so ?

Comment: Are you sure that these libraries are linked into mozilla? Is there any possibility that these library run in another service process?

Comment: No, the libraries are static.  The VS solution is not provided by Mozilla to build Firefox, the 'mach' build is entirely done from command line.  But you can generate the VS solution from the command line.  It shows the code in a pretty way and it is possible to use the solution to spike 'mach' commands.  But it doesn't seem to be instrumental in the building process.  Maybe that would explain the lack of breakpoints.